# displacement of the block down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This [page](http://jsfiddle.net/L46FX/78/) is made for bootstrap3.

With a large width of the screen, there are 2 columns `.left` and `.right`.
In the column `.left` there is a button `.more`.

I would like to [move](http://prozaik.16mb.com/responsive/q.png) the button to the bottom of the unit `.approach_r`

PS:
the amount of text in block `.right` may change

Comment: Not really the answer to your question, but you are overclassing your grid. The smallest grid setting will take precedence until overridden by a larger screen. So therefore, having `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4` can be reduced to just `col-xs-12 col-md-4`, as small screens will get the xs layout, and large screens will get the md layout.

Comment: Further, all columns will reset to col-*-12 if not specified, so `col-xs-12 col-md-4` is also overclassed. To achieve your layout, you only need `col-md-4` on the left and `col-md-8` on the right. See http://bootply.com/93906 for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you
check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/L46FX/123/)

```
.more {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: auto;
    top: 5px;
    z-index:5
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .more {
        bottom: 5px;
        top:auto;
    }
}
```